# Github packages: npm publish y problema al intentar instalar paquete

Tags: npm, github, packages

acabo de hacer una publicación de mi paquete en npm a través de github.

El repositorio es este:
https://github.com/diegoulloao/banana-cli

Pude autenticarme y hacer la publicación y al parecer todo iba bien, pero al hacer la instalación con:

`npm install @diegoulloao/banana-cli@1.0.0 -g` de forma global obtengo:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@diegoulloao%2fbanana-cli - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@diegoulloao/banana-cli@1.0.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

En el detalle (log) aparece esto:

```
diego:Desktop/ $ cat /Users/diego/.npm/_logs/2020-02-20T22_59_19_345Z-debug.log                                                               [19:59:19]
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '@diegoulloao/banana-cli@1.0.0',
1 verbose cli   '-g'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.7
3 info using node@v12.8.1
4 verbose npm-session 6244d0a7c6e7a1bd
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/@diegoulloao%2fbanana-cli 1831ms
8 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/@diegoulloao%2fbanana-cli 1078ms
9 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @diegoulloao/banana-cli@1.0.0 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@diegoulloao%2fbanana-cli - Not found
10 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
11 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 2939ms
12 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@diegoulloao%2fbanana-cli - Not found
12 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/check-response.js:104:15
12 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
13 verbose statusCode 404
14 verbose pkgid @diegoulloao/banana-cli@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/diego/Desktop
16 verbose Darwin 19.2.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "@diegoulloao/banana-cli@1.0.0" "-g"
18 verbose node v12.8.1
19 verbose npm  v6.13.7
20 error code E404
21 error 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@diegoulloao%2fbanana-cli - Not found
22 error 404
23 error 404 '@diegoulloao/banana-cli@1.0.0' is not in the npm registry.
24 error 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
25 error 404 Note that you can also install from a
26 error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
27 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

No sé qué irá mal. Al parecer el paquete no aparece en los registros:
https://registry.npmjs.org/@diegoulloao%2fbanana-cli

Obtengo un error 404 not found de respuesta del servidor.

Creo que agregué todo correctamente en mi package.json tal como dice la documentación de github: https://help.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-npm-for-use-with-github-packages.

Agradecería revisar dichos archivos para ver si estoy cometiendo algún error y ver si me pueden ayudar por favor.

URL del paquete que se publicó: https://github.com/diegoulloao/banana-cli/packages/133408

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Los registros de `npm` y de `Github` son diferentes. Cuando publicaste tu paquete donde lo hiciste fue en el de `Github`.

Cuando ejecutas `npm install` y la dependencia esta escrita como `<nombre>@<versión>` donde se busca es en el [registro](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry) configurado por defecto.

> npm está configurado para usar por defecto el registro público de npm, Inc. localizado en https://registry.npmjs.org

Para poder consumir un paquete de `Github` debes haber seguido el **punto 2** de la guía que estas leyendo, o sea, el npm debe estar configurado para consumir de

```
registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/OWNER
```

como el `OWNER` eres tú sería

```
registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/diegoulloao
```

Si tu módulo es público lo que te recomiendo es que uses el registro por defecto de `npm` ya que requiere menos configuración a la hora de instalar.

Comment: Hola, efectivamente era eso lo que me faltaba. Ahora el asunto es que sólo yo creando ese archivo podré consumir el paquete. Lo que deseo es que cualquiera pueda consumirlo sólo ejecutando npm install nombredelpaquete.

Entonces me sugieres publicarlo directamente desde npm? Además el paquete está diseñado para ser instalado de forma global.

Comment: @DiegoUlloa Si eso es exactamente lo que debes hacer. Cualquier instalación o configuración adicional que debas hacer solo hace más complicado de consumir tu módulo.

Comment: Ahí pude!! Muchas gracias!!!